# How to include source instead of a library in C# / Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I come from a long Java background and very new to C#. I was trying to run one of the [starter kit applications](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Phone-Starter-Kit-79e45e30#content) from Windows phone and I am getting this error.

```
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone.dll
```

I am finding it hard to debug this because I am directly referring to the dll file under References pointing to Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone. In Java, I would have [searched](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/89222) for the library and downloaded the source to step into the exact location during debugging.

If that is possible, how would I do it in C# (as in how would i refer the library source for my project to pick up at run-time)? I am using the Visual studio 2010 Express Edition as the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download the third party library you are dealing with
2. Add this library's project into your solution
3. In your project, remove the reference to the 3rd party library
4. Add a project dependency into your project, make it depend on the 3rd party library project you have just added to your solution
5. Compile and run, happy debugging

Comment: Step #1 i did. But i do not see any .csproj files. I only see .sln files. So i cannot add the project

Comment: There must be a project file under the solution, just look closely :)

Comment: It is under `trunk\src\newtonsoft.json\`

Comment: Great! Good luck and let me know if you run into trouble :)

Comment: Although i am running into other problems, this particular problem is solved :) Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is you should download last release of [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), remove the compiled library from your project's references and add reference to the source code project. (Add Reference... > Projects > Browse...)

Comment: @Jeff: True. I don't remember how to do it though.

Comment: @JeffN825 : By debug symbols, you mean the .pdb extension file ?

Comment: @DanAbramov: How to set the breakpoints, i mean where will be the source ?

Comment: @Bragboy: If you add Json.NET as a project to your solution, you will see its source next to your project's source.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have stopped your program in the debugger, you can use the [modules window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9.aspx) to load the symbols for Json.NET. Obviously, you need to have the symbols on your machine so you can browse to them.

Failing that, you can switch to a project reference and include Json.NET in your solution as Dan suggested.

Comment: thanks for that link. Since i am using the express edition, i don't have that privilege :(

Comment: +1 Replacing a referenced assembly with the source project is rarely the easiest way to debug one-off bugs, unless you plan to fix and patch it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download their latest build then inside visual studio right click your solution and under add menu select existing project point to project file of the library and click open button. after that u will be able to set brakepoint wherever u want.